# Text Input Gets Erased on Browser Resize in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am at my wits end here trying to figure out how to save form input in React Native Web/ReactJS when resizing the browser for my website. Basically, I have 3 versions of the site: desktop, tablet, and phone. I want whatever has been inputed into the message area to re-render with the same text when the browser size changes, but instead, it just erases whatever was entered.

I have the following code below. Thanks!

```
var Support = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
            message: ''};
    },

    handleResize: function(e) {
        this.setState({windowWidth: window.innerWidth, message: this.state.message});
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
    },
    saveMsg: function(text) {
        this.setState({message: text})
    },

    _checkScreenSize: function(e) {
        if (this.state.windowWidth > 774) {
           return <Desktop message={this.state.message} saveMsg={this.saveMsg}/>
        }
        else if (this.state.windowWidth > 596) {
            return <Tablet message={this.state.message} saveMsg={this.saveMsg}/>
        }
        else {
            return <Phone message={this.state.message} saveMsg={this.saveMsg}/>
        }
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <NavBar/>
                <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
                    <View>
                        <TitleBar name={'How Can We Help You?'} image={homeImage} windowWidth={this.state.windowWidth}/>
                        {this._checkScreenSize()}
                        <Footer/>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>

        )
    }
})

var Desktop = React.createClass({
    render() {
        var sizes={inputPrompt: 15, input: 18}
        return (
            <View style={[contentStyle.contentContainer, {marginLeft: 60, marginRight: 60}]}>
                <ContactForm size={sizes} message={this.props.message} saveMsg={this.props.saveMsg}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
})

var Tablet = React.createClass({
    render() {
        var sizes={inputPrompt: 13, input: 15}
        return (
            <View style={[contentStyle.contentContainer, {marginLeft: 30, marginRight: 30}]}>
                <ContactForm size={sizes} message={this.props.message} saveMsg={this.props.saveMsg}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
})

var Phone = React.createClass({
    render() {
        var sizes={inputPrompt: 11, input: 13}
        return (
            <View style={[contentStyle.contentContainer, {marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10}]}>
                <ContactForm size={sizes} message={this.props.message} saveMsg={this.props.saveMsg}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
})

var ContactForm = React.createClass({
   render() {
        return (
                <View style={contentStyle.contentContainer}>
                        <InputPrompt prompt={'Message*:'} size={this.props.size.inputPrompt}/>
                        <Message message={this.props.message} saveMsg={this.props.saveMsg}/>
                    </View>

        )
    }
})

var Message = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <TextInput style={[styles.multiLineInput, GenerateFont(this.props.size, '#1C1C1C')]}
                multiline = {true}
                numberOfLines = {4}
                message={this.props.message}
                onChangeText={(text) => {this.props.saveMsg(text);
                }}/>
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that when I do test prints in the console, the message is being saved in support and accurately passed back down the chain to the message rendering box, it's just not rendering in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Problem was with the onChangeText function. All I needed to do was add a default value in Message and set it to this.props.message.